# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have got 6 NSMutableArray(monday,tuesday...saturday) which I add to NSMutableArray "day"
I doing in this method " numberOfRowsInSection "

```
NSArray *array = [day objectAtIndex:section];
return [array count];
```

all work, but when I add item I have item only when I rebuild project or if I delete a row I have got error

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).

if I doing this method everything works but i need doing the first method, in two-three lines

```
if(section==0)
  return [monday count];
if(section==1)
  return [tuesday count];
if(section==2)
  return [wednesday count];
if(section==3)
  return [thirsday count];
if(section==4)
  return [friday count];
if(section==5)
  return [saturday count];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must remove object in your array when you delete tableview cell.
if you remove cell at section one row one,you should:

```
[[day objectAtIndex:one] removeObjectAtIndex:one];
```